# what is wrong with this MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
  public function getfriends($username){        

    //  gets a users friends by username... does cross checking and joins the users table to it so we can get other data without having to do another query
        $sql = "SELECT S.ts, S.stats, S.image, PI.rusername, PI.arefriend,
                       PI.tusername AS friend
                FROM friends PI
                JOIN users S ON PI.tusername = S.username
                WHERE S.username = PI.tusername
                AND PI.tusername!=:username
                AND PI.rusername=:username
                AND S.username!=:username
                UNION
                SELECT S.ts, S.stats, S.image, PI.tusername, PI.arefriend,
                       PI.rusername AS friend
                FROM friends PI
                JOIN users S ON PI.rusername = S.username
                WHERE S.username = PI.rusername
                AND PI.rusername!=:username
                AND PI.tusername=:username";

        $stmt = db::prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt->rowCount())
        {
            // Loop through the assoc array and create a new array we can return
            // after processing is done.

// fetch assoc as suggested by Jon removes the duplicates
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $xrow[]=$row;
            }
            return $xrow;   
        } elseif(!$stmt->rowCount()) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

This is my function which is part of a class you basically give it a username and it selects all friends for that user and puts them in an array. So that I can then loop through the results wherever I am calling this function form. Theres these 2 columns in the friends database table called tusername and rusername. this is basically keeping track of who sent a friends request to who. its short for tousername and requestusername.

Now somewhere some values are getting lost this is a printr of the data returned

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ts] => 2014-01-15 08:27:17
            [stats] => 
            [image] => uploads/girl.jpg
            [rusername] => nasser
            [arefriend] => 2
            [friend] => girl
        )

)
```

As you can see rusername is there but tusername is missing and the data in tusername is wrong swell its just showing the username that was passed into the getfriends function.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Have you tried using a LEFT JOIN? instead of a regular join?

Comment: There are several redundant statements in your query. I suggest you post up an sqlfiddle, together with the desired result.

Comment: I see one thing in your sql (not the fault, that's why I put it in comment.
ON PI.tusername = S.username WHERE S.username = PI.tusername 
You can remove the 'ON PI.tusername = S.username' or you can remove the 'S.username = PI.tusername'

Comment: Thanks :) Would be great if you could help fix it :)

Comment: Hi chillworld, do you know why theres duplicate items in my array?

Comment: If I remove the S.username = PI.tusername... should I remove the where or the And at the end? WHERE S.username = PI.tusername AND

Comment: `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` will remove the duplicates

Comment: Hi Jon, Thank you so much thats removed the duplicates. :)

Any ideas how I can get tusername to show up in my array would be nice :) and maybe improve the query :)

Comment: Why are you expecting to see 'tusername'? You gave it an alias: 'friend', which is what you're seeing in the results. Now, if 'friend' doesn't have the expected value, that's a different problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out Phil :) Now I get it :)

Comment: I managed to fix it thanks Phil :) +1

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why you using union here .

try this

```
   SELECT S.ts, S.stats, S.image, PI.rusername, PI.arefriend,
               PI.tusername AS friend
        FROM friends PI
        JOIN users S ON PI.tusername = S.username
        WHERE S.username!=:username
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, I did try your code but unfortunately it didn't even print out the array at all, any ideas? :)

Comment: I did manage to get your query working but it doesn't work perfectly... if I request for 1 user it works.. if i request for a user in the tusername column it works...but if i request data for rusername because its only joining the data where theres tusername... it doesn't return anything.

Any idea how I can make it check if the username is in tusername or in rusername and then join users onto that?

Comment: can you make an example data or fiddle if you can and a wished result .